# Local Notification banner shows different text than what i set in alert action property

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

Here is my code to set local notifications for Event but it shows different text for different iphones like , for some iPhone it shows "Slide for more" and for some it shows "Touch to open" where as i set "view details" message:

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;

localNotification.alertTitle = self.titleCell.propertyValue;

localNotification.alertBody =  self.titleCell.propertyValue;    

localNotification.alertAction = @"view details";
```

Comment: Your different devices must be having different OS version, thats why.

Comment: then what is solution to have my custom message for alert action like 'slide to open' instead of 'slide for more'

Comment: There is no problem at first place, it is defined and handled by OS, you can't do anything about it.

Comment: I think iphonic is talking about the new framework in iOS 10. See [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/)

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    UIAlertView *notificationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification"    message:@"This local notification" 
    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [notificationAlert show];//use latest alert action

}
```

**yourControler.m**

```
-(IBAction)startLocalNotification {  // Bind this method to UIButton action
NSLog(@"startLocalNotification");

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:7];
notification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];    
}
```

**you need register for local notification**

```
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){

[application registerUserNotificationSettings [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```